# How to integrate slack channel to SharePoint with embedded code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, slack, slack-api, spfx, sharepointframework

I am using SharePoint Online. I have created a SharePoint Framework web part and added it to the page.

I need to integrate the embedded code of the Slack channel into the iframe under the SPFx web part.

How can I get the embedded code of the Slack channel from Slack?

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SPFx and react as template, it should be possible by using one of many react packages from npm.
Have you tried this one?? -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/embedded-slack-react

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the npm package. This package creates a div for a chat at the bottom right. My actual requirement is needed to display the slack channel under a specific div on the SharePoint page.